# How can I return the value of a deferred method in javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo, deferred, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to write a module which projects coordinates into a new Spatial Reference, but the javascript syntax has beaten me once again.

This is how the module currently looks like:

```
define(["esri/geometry/Point", ...], 
    function(Point, SpatialReference, ...){

    var gmsvc = new GeometryService("http://server/maps/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer");
    /*...*/

    return {
        /*...*/
        //transforms the current point on the map to the new wkid
        transformCoordinates: function(point, newWkId) {

            var param = new ProjectParameters();
            var newPoint;
            param.geometries = [point];
            param.outSR = new SpatialReference({ wkid: newWkId});

            gmsvc.project(param);

            gmsvc.on('project-complete', function(result) {
                newPoint = result.geometries[0];
            });

            return newPoint;
        }   
    };
});
```

As per the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice.html#project) `GeometryService.project(parameter)` is marked as deferred, so I try to access the result of it in the OnProjectComplete event. At this point `result.geometries[0]` is a valid Point with an x, y and SpatialReference property.
Assigning this to the `newPoint` variable and returning it, results in an `undefined` being returned:

```
console.log(CoordinateTransUtils.transformCoordinates(evt.mapPoint, 5254));
> undefined
```

Changing the code to

```
return gmsvc.on('project-complete', function(result) {
    return result.geometries[0];
});
```

results in a return value of:

```
Object {id: 216, receiveArguments: true, previous: Object}advice: (){var b,c={},e=arguments.length;for(b=0;b<e;b++)c[f[b]]=arguments[b];c.target||(c.target=d);a.call(d,c)}id: 216next: Objectprevious: ObjectreceiveArguments: trueremove: (){if(h.advice){var c=h.previous,d=h.next;!d&&!c?delete b[e]:(c?c.next=d:b[e]=d,d&&(d.previous=c));b=a=h.advice=null}}__proto__: Object
```

which isn't a point either.
My question therefore is, how to return the point stored in `result.geometries[0]` with an explanation what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: You cannot. It's asynchronous.

Comment: I just found out, that if I scope `newPoint` to the define method I can. the question is why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `newPoint` will only actually set *after* the `return` statement is already processed, so it's undefined when that line runs.

Generally, if something within your function's logic is asynchronous, your function in itself will need to be asynchronous in nature as well.  Typically in these cases it is recommended to return a promise.  e.g.:

```
    transformCoordinates: function(point, newWkId) {
        var dfd = new Deferred(); // (from dojo/Deferred)
        var param = new ProjectParameters();
        param.geometries = [point];
        param.outSR = new SpatialReference({ wkid: newWkId});

        gmsvc.project(param);

        gmsvc.on('project-complete', function(result) {
            dfd.resolve(result.geometries[0]);
        });
        // If there is an accompanying error event, you should also
        // listen to that and call dfd.reject in its handler.

        return dfd.promise;
    }
```

See the [Deferred](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/deferreds/index.html) and [Promise](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/promises/index.html) tutorials for more information.

Comment: As a temporary solution I've declared newPoint before the return block. It kind of works. Could you elaborate why this is/isn't a good solution?

Comment: That will only "kind of" work insofar as it will still be undefined until the event actually fires, so you're creating a race condition by doing that.  Your `transformCoordinates` function is still definitely going to return undefined.  This is the toughest and most important lesson in asynchronous callback-based programming - just because your code is written in a certain order doesn't mean it's executing in that order.  The code in that event callback happens sometime after control has already returned from that function.

Comment: I had to adapt how I consume this deferred method now by adding a `then(function(results{ ... }))` to the caller and now it works.